# Cannot install QGIS 3 on Ubuntu 18.04 (From ubuntu repo. Not ubuntugis-unstable )

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu

When I want to install QGIS latest ver 3.3.4 to ubuntu 18.04 it rises error bellow :

Setting up qgis-providers (1:3.4.4+28bionic) ...
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
 installed qgis-providers package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
 qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 1:3.4.4+28bionic); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-grass:
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis (= 1:3.4.4+28bionic); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:

qgis-providers

qgis

qgis-plugin-grass

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I have removed it several times and install again but the problem still remains.

I use repository :
https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic main